# making dropdown boxes links that open in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I found this code here:

```
<select id="my_selection">
<option value="x" href="/link/to/somewhere">value 1</option>
<option value="y" href="/link/to/somewhere/else">value 2</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');
}
</script>
```

And it works just fine for what it's intended, it makes dropdown box items into links. I was wondering if there's a way to make those links open in a new windows, rather then just redirecting?  I'm just getting into coding/programming, so I struggle with a lot of the easy things that most experienced programmers just take for granted. Thanks!

Comment: window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href'),"_blank"); -  it will have issues with popup blockers. Also since you are not using the value, why not use that for the hrefs?

Comment: I am not sure you mean by that. `<option selected="selected" href="mylink.com">Mylink</option> Can i put `target="new"` after the link url, as an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer.
Please note the "Please select" to allow the first URL to be selected.

```
<select id="my_selection">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="/link/to/somewhere">value 1</option>
  <option value="/link/to/somewhere/else">value 2</option>
</select>
```

using

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
    var href= this.value;
    if (href) {
      var win = window.open(href,"_blank");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.open
```

in place of

```
window.location.href
```

for more details of window.open Please check this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: If you mean just replace `window.location.href` with `window.open` that seems to have disabled..they are no longer working links. And I did check any popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
window.open (this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

This should be what you're looking for, it opens the link in a new tab/window.